# Is there a way to create a batch file that creates a folder in a sequenced order?

Tags: batch-file

I currently have a batch file that creates folders, sub-folders, and copies template files and changes the names of these files.

I am trying to create another batch that is called by my original batch to make a new folder in a different directory.

I have folders 1-66 and am trying to get the new batch to create "67 New Project Name"

I know how to call a batch I just need help with the code for creating a new folder that goes up in 1 number after reading the previous number.

This is my original batch

```
@echo off

SET "pname=New Project Name"

for %%a in ("Bid Proposals" "Reports" "Drawings" "Specifications"
 "Addenda") do md "%pname%\%%~a"

cd /d  K:\ESTIMATING\2019 ESTIMATING\2019 BID-PROPOSALS\%pname%\Bid Proposals
copy "K:\User\Estimating Tools\Bid Proposal - Template.docx" .
rename "Bid Proposal - Template.docx" "%pname% - Bid Proposal.docx"

cd /d  K:\ESTIMATING\2019 ESTIMATING\2019 BID-PROPOSALS\%pname%\Specifications
copy "K:\User\Estimating Tools\Bid Package Info Sheet fillable in progress.pdf" 
rename "Bid Package Info Sheet fillable in progress.pdf" "%pname% - Bid Package Info Sheet.pdf"
```

I think I must create a new batch that is in the folder I want to create the new subfolders.

Then Call it from this batch.

the new batch will create "67.(or whatever the next number up is) %pname%" in  C:\Users's Tiffs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this, assuming the start of each file is numeric, and the file numbers are not being created out of order, as we are sorting by datetime.

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "destDir=K:\ESTIMATING\2019 ESTIMATING\2019 BID-PROPOSALS"
set "sourceDir=K:\User\Estimating Tools"

call :GetCounterVal
if "%ctr%"=="0" (
    @echo Cannot locate a counter value
    goto :eof
)

SET "pname=%ctr% New Project Name"

for %%a in ("Bid Proposals" "Reports" "Drawings" "Specifications" "Addenda") do md "%pname%\%%~a"

cd /d  "%destDir%\%pname%\Bid Proposals"
copy "%sourceDir%\Bid Proposal - Template.docx" .
rename "Bid Proposal - Template.docx" "%pname% - Bid Proposal.docx"

cd /d  "%destDir%\%pname%\Specifications"
copy "%sourceDir%\Bid Package Info Sheet fillable in progress.pdf" 
rename "Bid Package Info Sheet fillable in progress.pdf" "%pname% - Bid Package Info Sheet.pdf"
goto :EOF

:GetCounterVal
    :: iterate the files in desc order by date/time
    for /f "eol=: delims=" %%F in ('dir /AD /O-D /B "%*New Project Name*"') do (
        :: read first file, then exit loop
        call :getFile %%F
        goto :break
    )
    :break

    if not "%ctr%"=="0" (set /A ctr=ctr+1)
    @echo New value is %ctr%
goto :EOF

:getFile
    :: Cheap way to automatically parse everything left of first space
    :: If parameter is not a number, it will be set to zero
    set /A ctr=%1
    @echo Last value is %ctr%
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Do I put the section before the break in the first batch and then the other half in the second batch? I am fairly new to this.

Comment: there are a number of ways to do it, I will edit the response to get you going.